# On the UK visa application, what should the cost of accommodation be for my wife and son?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-accommodation

I am in the UK with an ICT visa (3 years). I am applying for a Standard Visitor visas for 6 months for my wife and son to visit me for 6 weeks. Now, as I already have accommodation, my wife and son can stay with me. How do I answer these:

1) The cost of your accommodation? 
I already have accommodation, so should I put 0 here?

2) Is someone other than you paying for all or a part of your trip?
If I put *No* here and most of the amount in our joint accounts have been credited recently (like within 1 month),  will my wife's bank statements be required here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1: Answer ‘0’ and explain in the application/cover letter that your family will be staying with you during their visit. If you do not own your accommodation, provide proof that you are allowed to have guests eg rental agreement, letter from landlord

Q2: Answer ‘yes’ if your wife is not paying all the costs of the trip herself. Your wife should submit her bank statements. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

This guidance may help https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589168/VAF1-guidance.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I am sponsoring complete trip then my Indian account statements will work because I have been in UK for just 3weeks and do not have any bank account here?